# How can I use __future__ division in the IDLE startup file

Tags: python, division, future, python-idle

In Python 2.7, how can I make the IDLE app use `\__future__ division` without typing `from \__future__ import division` manually every time I start IDLE?

If I put `from \__future__ import division` at the top of my .idlestartup file it is ignored, even though the other things in .idlestartup get executed. For example:

```
~> cat >.idlestartup
from __future__ import division
print("Executing .idlestartup")
~> idle -s
```

Here's what my IDLE window looks like after I try dividing:

```
Python 2.7.8 |Anaconda 2.1.0 (x86_64)| (default, Aug 21 2014, 15:21:46) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)] on darwin
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
Executing .idlestartup
>>> 2/3
0
>>>
```

I am using Mac OS X 10.9.5 Mavericks (also had the same problem on earlier versions of OS X). Note that the command line version above was included to make it easier to show what I'm talking about, but the version I'm more interested in is running the IDLE app from the GUI.

The solution suggested by Ashwini Chaudhary below worked for running the Anaconda version from the command line but not for running the IDLE app.

I was finally able to get future division working automatically in the IDLE app by adding "sys.argv.insert(1, '-Qnew')" to /Applications/IDLE.app/Contents/MacOS/IDLE. Both that and Ashwini Chaudhary's solution below seem brittle. I wonder if there is a cleaner way.

Comment: If you put a `print 5/3` in the file you will see it actually works initially but then gets overridden somehow

Comment: Since this might be a fixable bug, I opened CPython tracker issue [22893](http://bugs.python.org/issue22893) with a link back to this question.

Comment: This should only be a problem in the Shell.  You can put the future import in a file that you edit.  Interactively, you can make either the numerator or denominator a float by adding `.0` to a literal or wrapping either in `float()`.  Or you can upgrade to 3.x.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the `__future__` statement at the top of `/usr/lib/python2.7/idlelib/PyShell.py` did the job for me.

I am on Ubuntu, the path may vary for other OS:

```
>>> import idlelib
>>> idlelib.PyShell.__file__
'/usr/lib/python2.7/idlelib/PyShell.py'
```

Comment: Just remember that one has to redo custom patches to stdlib files after upgrading to a new 2.7.z bugfix version.

Comment: Editing /anaconda/lib/python2.7/idlelib/PyShell.py solved the problem for running idle -s from the command line (which I currently runs the anaconda version), but that didn't solve the problem when running the IDLE app. I tried to do the same edit to the PyShell.py in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/idlelib, which I verified is the one that is used by the IDLE app, but it did not work. (In fact, IDLE wouldn't start up; I think it might be because the .pyc file it creates is different from the old one, even if I create it with sudo.)